# Copying objects bug in Flutter BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app with Flutter using BLOC Architecture with the flutter_bloc package.

I have a data class for an object, which looks like this example:

```
class MyClass {
  int? id;
  List<MyOtherClass> myOtherClasses = [];

  MyClass();

  MyClass._(this.id, this.myOtherClasses);

  MyClass copyWith({int? id, List<MyOtherClass>? myOtherClasses}) {
    return MyClass._(
      id ?? this.id,
      myOtherClasses ?? this.myOtherClasses,
    );
  }
}

class MyOtherClass {
  int value;

  MyOtherClass(this.value);
}
```

Now I a Screen that shows the values of the class, and a Dialog to edit it. To store the state, I am using a Cubit, that looks like this:

```
@immutable
abstract class MyClassState {
  final MyClass myClass;

  MyClassState(this.myClass);
}

class MyClassInitial extends MyClassState {
  MyClassInitial() : super(MyClass());
}

class MyClassEditing extends MyClassState {
  final MyClass editingMyClass;

  MyClassEditing(MyClass myClass, this.editingMyClass) : super(myClass);
}

class MyClassChanged extends MyClassState {
  MyClassChanged(MyClass myClass) : super(myClass);
}

class MyClassCubit extends Cubit<MyClassState> {
  MyClassCubit() : super(MyClassInitial());

  void editMyClass({int? id, List<MyOtherClass>? myOtherClasses}) {
    emit(MyClassEditing(state.myClass,
        state.myClass.copyWith(id: id, myOtherClasses: myOtherClasses)));
  }

  void saveChanges() {
    if (state is MyClassEditing)
      emit(MyClassChanged((state as MyClassEditing).editingMyClass));
  }

  void discardChanged() {
    emit(MyClassChanged(state.myClass));
  }
}
```

So, basically, what I am trying to achieve here is to story a backup of `MyClass` in the `MyClassEditing` state in order to be able to discard the changes I made to `MyClass`. When I call the constructor of `MyClassEditing` here in this line: `emit(MyClassEditing(state.myClass, state.myClass.copyWith(id: id, myOtherClasses: myOtherClasses)));`, the state should contain the initial instance of `MyClass` without any changes, and the copy of the initial `MyClass` instance with the changes applied. But somehow, both instances have the changes applied, and I just don't get why this happens. Am I doing something wrong copying the instance?

Comment: Could you provide consumer code? Which calls these methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the issue might be lists, if you make shallow copy of them.

Comment: Hi! Jep, that was the reason. In the copyWith() Method, I changed `myOtherClasses ?? this.myOtherClasses` to `myOtherClasses != null ? List.of(myOtherClasses) : this.myOtherClasses`. Thanks!